# Unexpected file using shutil.make_archive to compress file

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, shutil

I am trying to use shutil.make_archive to zip files.

When I am using :

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('zip_file', 'zip', 'C:\\Users\\test')
```

I got a zip_file in the zip_file, and the zip_file in the zip_file seems to be a corrupted file. Anyone knows how to deal with it?

However, when I am using :

```
make_archive(
  'zipfile_name', 
  'zip',           # the archive format - or tar, bztar, gztar 
  root_dir=file_dir,   # root for archive - current working dir if None
  base_dir=file_dir)   # start archiving from here - cwd if None too
```

It gets everything correct except the folder directory wrong.
For example, if file_dir = 'C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\test\bbb'
The structure of the zip file will be:

```
 Users  
         aaa
              Desktop
                     test
                         bbb
```

And I wish it could be bbb/ only.

Any thoughts? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to create the zipfile in a different directory.  From there, something like

```
shutil.make_archive('zip_file', 'zip', 'C:\\Users\\test', "bbb")
```

should give you an archive of the bbb directory.

Comment: Sure it works, but why does it fail to create a zip file of itself in that particular directory ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my suspicion is that the zipfile is created as the first step in the process, then filled by a walk through the target directory.  As the zipfile is in the target directory, it sees an unfinished version of itself, which it includes.

Comment: That makes sense. And that explained why it didn't show up in another folder. Thank you so much.